# Arithmetic and Algebra exercises on latex source code.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, education

I´m currently writing a little book for two student that I teach. The book covers school arithmetics and algebra, and it include theory and examples. Since I don´t have time to prepare a good sets of problems, I would like to know if there is any site where I can download exercises in latex code, since I´m using latex to write the book.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[ShareLatex](https://www.sharelatex.com/) is a very good tool and answer to your question. ;)